# What are the differences between pneumatic nail types like "smooth" and "ring" for house framing?

Tags: framing, materials, fastener, nails

I'm getting my material list together to frame a house and am a bit confused by all the similar looking pneumatic nails which all have a slightly different wording/features and different prices, sometimes subtle and sometimes not.

On the takeoff a lumber yard created for me, there are several types of nails listed. They are:

- Pneu-Fast PF SP12D 3-1/4" x 0.131" NA
- Pneu-Fast SP8D 2-3/8" x 113 2.5M RS Ring Shank Bright
- HITACHI HI13367 2 1/4X092 RG HDG
- GGNC15 1-1/4X120W PS GV 7.2M

I believe the last two are for siding and roofing respectively. But when are SP12D nails used vs SP8D when framing?

Second, when I look these nails up, there are actually several flavors and options for the same size nail:

- Ring Hot Galvanized
- Smooth Brite Ring
- Brite Ring
- Hot Galvanized
- Smooth Hot Galvanized

What do these terms mean, and when should I use a certain type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Definitions**

- Hot galvanized: Dipped in molten zinc as an anti-corrosion measure. The alternative is electro-plating, which results in a smoother but thinner coating.
- Brite: Not galvanized. Usually not cement-coated.
- Smooth: An untextured shank. Regular nails. Often coated with yellow or magenta "cement", a bonding agent that noticeably increases pullout resistance.
- Ring: Ring-textured shanks for improved pullout resistance.

**Usage**

You'll use 12d (twelve penny, 3 or 3-1/4") smooth nails for most framing. We actually refer to those as 16d as they're the functional equivalent of 16d sinkers. They may be cement coated. Nails used with the current crop of pressure-treated wood often need to be galvanized or stainless to prevent accelerated corrosion.

You'll use 8d (eight penny, 2, 2-1/4", or 2-3/8") ring-shank nails for subflooring if not using screws.

Comment: Since this is  slab on grade, single story house, what else could the 8d nails be used for? Is it a mistake?

Comment: That's a question for your lumber salesperson. Practices and techniques vary, and I know very little about your project.

Comment: 8d 2-3/8 ring-shank nails are whats recommended in my area for attaching plywood or OSB sheathing to framing members.

Comment: Ah. Could be that it's different for hurricane-prone areas. Around here we use narrow-crown staples (which also hold like crazy).